# Convert long timestamp to Java.util.Date in french

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to know how I can convert a timestamp in the date format.
For example : 1415337782000 should be converted to "7 nov. 2014".

This is what I've tried  so far :

```
Date date=new Date(location.date);
SimpleDateFormat df = (SimpleDateFormat) SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM);
String dateText = df.format(date);
```

The timestamp is stored in location.date in long type.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And what was the result? What is your default locale?

Comment: (It's not clear why you're mentioning `SimpleDateFormat` at all, btw. Better to use `DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(...)` - after all, `getDateInstance` is a static method declared in `DateFormat`...)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a format to the SimpleDateFormat constructor, like this

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM, yyyy");
String dateText = format.format(new Date());
```

You can find the constants in this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

For better internationalization, you can define a string resource containing the desired format based on the location of the user. Something like

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat(getResources().getString(R.string.YOUR_FORMAT));
```